# Is "Unsung hero" badge unavailable?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

I don't see the Unsung Hero badge in my *Choose which badge to track*, but I still received the *Tenacious* badge a few weeks ago.

Does this mean that the listed badge is unavailable or does it just not appear in that section?

Comment: Probably just a UI bug.  The [Unsung hero](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) badge is still being awarded.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The badge just doesn't appear in that section.

Unsung Hero is impossible to track; you need to have enough accepted answers that are not voted on that are all at least 10 days old or older. Any of those answers could get an upvote at any point in time.

It's a surprise badge, not something you can even hope to aim for.

As such, there really is no point in letting you track it in your profile. It'll just encourage people to dumb down their answers after getting accepted, to avoid upvotes, otherwise.