# Understanding unsung hero badge

Tags: discussion, badge-progress

I've found [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197953/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=9942418) that shows the current progress of getting the unsung hero badge, but I can't seem to understand it. Do I need to have this *Percentage Unscored* higher than 25 to get the badge? What are *Scored* and *Unscored* answers then?

Comment: Of interest: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293658/is-unsung-hero-badge-unavailable , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256747/why-did-i-not-get-the-unsung-hero-badge and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256155/does-getting-unsung-hero-gold-badge-mean-that-you-post-low-quality-answers

Comment: Also see [What does the "Tenacious" badge mean?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261690)

Comment: @MartijnPieters off-topic observation: Your link is not listed in the "linked" section on the right. I wonder why not.

Comment: @Gimby: it's a protocol-relative comment, [which are explicitly ignored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291236/protocol-relative-and-relative-urls-should-be-considered-linked). I use [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper) to provide titles and that shortens the URL. I'll see if they want to include the protocol in the URL anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scored = has a score other than 0.

Unscored = has a score of 0.

For the unsung hero badge, at least 25% of your accepted answers need to have a score of exactly 0. This means you don't have much control over getting the badge. You can easily get it if you frequently answer questions on low-activity tags, but it's nearly impossible to get on high-activity tags.

Comment: Oh I'd totally misunderstood the badge. So I need to NOT get upvoted to actually get it?

Comment: Yup. You can consider it a consolation prize for people investing in low-activity tags, because they're missing out on the usual upvotes on good answers.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy: that what makes this badge so hard to get. Not only do you need to not get upvoted, you also need to post a lot of answers if you are also active in tags that do see more traffic. I'll never, ever qualify, that's for sure. I'm a good 15% away from Tenacious, so ~2000 accepted answers at 0, at my rates.

Comment: do answers count that have 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes? Hence equaling 0, or do these need to be un-voted accepted answers? Just curious as I couldn't find any info about this. My guess is unscored as in no votes at all :P

Comment: Ah. I'd also misunderstood. 25% of your _accepted answers_ must be zero-score. I thought it was 25% of your answers must be _accepted with zero score_.